# Load more articles from json feed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need your help with some ajax/jquery request to load more articles from json feed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var output = $('#news');
var count = "2";
var page = "1";
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://domain.com/api/get_recent_posts/?post_type=news&count=' + count + '&page=' + page + '&callback=?',
    async: false,
    callback: 'callback',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function (data, status) {
        $.each(data.posts, function (i, item) {
            var news = '<li>' + item.title + '</li>';
            output.append(news);
        });

        if (data !== undefined && data !== undefined) {
            $('#stats').append('Page ' + page + ' of ' + data.pages + ' | Total posts ' + data.count_total + '');
        }

    },
    error: function () {
        output.html('<h1 class="error">There was an error loading the data.</h2>');
    }
});
});
```

What do I need is: by clicking on the link (load more) page should display titles from "var page = '2'" and so on but when it reaches last page the link should disappear. hope it does make sense.

Please see live fiddle below:
http://jsfiddle.net/AGGjj/

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I see no click event on the link ? You should increment the `page` and `count` values to load a new url.

Comment: `if (data !== undefined && data !== undefined)`? Double-checking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every one who would have the answer:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var output = $('#news');
var count = "2";
var page = "1";
var load = function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://domain.com/api/get_recent_posts/?post_type=news&count=' + count + '&page=' + page + '&callback=?',
    async: false,
    callback: 'callback',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function (data, status) {
        $.each(data.posts, function (i, item) {
            output.append($('<li />').text(item.title));
        });

        if (data !== undefined && data !== undefined) {
            $('#stats').text('Page ' + page + ' of ' + data.pages + ' | Total posts ' + data.count_total + '');
        }
        if (page == data.pages) {
             $("#loadmore").remove();
        }
        page++;

    },
    error: function () {
        output.html('<h2 class="error">There was an error loading the data.</h2>');
    }
});
};
//add click handler
$('#loadmore').click(function() {load();});
//load first page
$('#loadmore').trigger('click');
//or
load();
});
```

Comment: Million thanks JoDev, is there any way how to avoid multiplying - Page 1 of 3 | Total posts 6

Comment: It's already done. I see this issue in same time :) I just replace ".append" by ".text"

Comment: You are an amazing developer JoDev!

Answer (score 0):

In the end of the success function add

```
success: function (data, status) {
    $.each(data.posts, function (i, item) {
        var news = '<li>' + item.title + '</li>';
        output.append(news);
    });

    if (data !== undefined && data !== undefined) {
        $('#stats').append('Page ' + page + ' of ' + data.pages + ' | Total posts ' + data.count_total + '');
    //just test if the current page is the last one
    if(page == data.pages) {
       $('link selector').hide();
       or remove
       $('link selector').remove();

    }
    }

},
```

Comment: How can I display more articles, at the moment it does only show 2 from page 1 but I need to display two more from page 2 by clicking on Load More and so on till I reach last page and then Load More should be removed

Comment: Don't forget to increment the "page" variable at the end of success function ( page++; ).

Comment: I am really sorry for asking again but I am completely nut in jquer/ajax, could you please tweak my fiddle? Really appreciate your help JoDev.

Comment: Ok, it's done. You forgot to add click handler like soyuka says.

Comment: In the future, do not post new answers; edit your existing answer.